# Two clicks required to redirect after fetch request?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am attempting to push some data to a route in my API, and then redirect the user all in one click.

For some reason, it requires two clicks to accomplish this. After the first click, the data does go to the API route I've directed it to, and I get a `?` in the header - but no redirect. Upon clicking the button again, it redirects to the page I indicated in the redirect function - without completing the fetch request.

```
function trialfunc() {
        console.log('Testfuncfre')

        var free_trial = 'True'
        fetch('/checkout_stripe_trial', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: free_trial
            }),
        }).then(redirectfunc2);

        }

function redirectfunc2() {

        console.log('redirectfunc2')

        window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/account2";

    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="subscription-form2">
    <button type="submit" style="background-color: gray" id='Subscribe' onclick="trialfunc()">Free Trial</button>

</form>
```

How can I get this code to perform both actions in a single click of the button?

Comment: You do not cancel the submit event on the form

Comment: @epascarello So the button type should be different?